# Masking some part of string from the right with XXXX using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to mask some part of string using SQL, for e.g if the string is

```
'example test 156425648'
```

I just want to mask the first 5 characters of the number from the right to i.e

```
'example test XXXXX5648'
```

masking will always be from the right.

I wanted this mask to be done in the select query itself, someone please help me with the query for it.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Do you mean from the left?

Comment: from the right.

Comment: Your example masks the first 5 from the left

Comment: I think it is neither left nor right but somewhere in the middle. The string in question is `example test 156425648`

Comment: from the left the string can be of any characters long, but from the right it is always going to be 9 numeric numbers. and from the 9 numeric numbers , I want to mask the first 5 of them with xxxxx

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you use the `stuff()` function with `patindex()` and `replicate()`:

```
select stuff(str, patindex('%[0-9]%', str), 5, replicate('X', 5))
from (values ('example test 156425648')) v(str);
```

If you know the numbers are at the end of the string, you can still use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(str, len(str) - 8, 5, replicate('X', 5))
from (values ('example test 156425648')) v(str);
```

From the way the question is phrased, I have no reason to think that the number is in a fixed position, though.

Answer (score 2):

According to your reqirements that the number will always be 9 digits long and at the end of the string:

```
declare @value varchar(100) = 'example test 156425648';
select left(@value, len(@value) - 9) + 'XXXXX' + right(@value, 4)
```

will give:

```
example test XXXXX5648
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a44bb784e52a5dc828dc9434f6d969e).

Comment: You said on Gordan's answer that it wouldn't work for value like `'example 123456789 test 156425648'`, however, your answer suffers the same problem in reverse. If you think it's important that Gordan's answer handles multiple values to be anonymised, shouldn't yours do so? Not saying this is wrong, just seems odd to point out a "flaw" in another answer, but not address it yourself.

Comment: @Larnu check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a6a6ba42ae03327de8349f76b48e93d8. Where is the problem?

Comment: That displays the problem; `'example 123456789 test XXXXX5648'`, not `'example XXXXX6789 test XXXXX5648'`.

Comment: No it does not. The result is `example 123456789 test XXXXX5648`.Did you cjeck the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it proved my point. `'123456789'` was not anonymised.

Comment: Let me ask. Do you think that the OP wants the result to be: `example XXXXX6789 test XXXXX5648`? This is not what the OP wants. The requirement is: `example 123456789 test XXXXX5648`

Comment: The op states *"I just want to mask the first 5 characters of the number from the right to i.e"*. There are 2 numbers in that string, so the first characters of **both** numbers should be masked.

Comment: Read the comments: *from the left the string can be of any characters long, but from the right it is always going to be 9 numeric numbers. and from the 9 numeric numbers , I want to mask the first 5 of them with xxxxx*

Comment: This is why I dislike it when users that don't put what they need in their question... I would suggest this could be ambiguous still though (and wouldn't surprise me with the drip feeding from the OP).

Comment: Anyway I see that Gordon Linoff edited so I should delete my comment